# Scanf and strings in c++

Tags: c++, scanf

I have a really simple program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct scholar{
    int number;
    string fam;
    int ocen;
};


int main(){
    int len;

    printf("vvedite n");
    scanf("%d", &len);
    scholar *barr= new scholar[len];

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        printf("Nomer studenta ");
        scanf("%d", &barr[i].number);
        printf("\nFamilia ");
        scanf("%s", barr[i].fam);
        printf("\nOcenka");
        scanf("%d", &barr[i].ocen);
    }
        delete [] bar;
```

But on line, where I want to input family, there is a warning:

```
warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'string'
(aka 'basic_string<char>') [-Wformat].
```

Any suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: Use `std::cin` and `std::vector` instead of `scanf` and a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `scanf` to `std::string`, C function has no idea what C++ implementation is. You could use `std::getline`

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::getline(std::cin, barr[i].fam);
```

Also, don't mix C code with C++ code, and should avoid `new` if possible, use vector of `scholar` instead. For sample:

```
std::vector<scholar> barr;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i have to using just simple arrays instead of vectors. Also, i need to input all 3 things(number, fam and ocen) in 1 line, i knew how to do it with just 1 scanf, but how can i do it with 2 scanf and 1 getline? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

'scanf' is defined in stdio.h which is a C library not a c++ library, so you could's transform
the type 'char*' to 'string' automatically. You can use other Input IO stream function not 'scanf'.